# How do I protect front-end javaScript code from being stolen?

Tags: javascript

How do I protect front-end javaScript code from being stolen?

I have an underscore, jQuery, and Backbone application.  It is a prototype and doesn't have many users and the back-end code is pretty trivial.  Hence any value is in the front end code.  How can I protect this code from being stolen/cloned.

Is minifying enough?  There are tools such as beautify that can be used to un-minify the code, but is this something that can be used to steal code?

What is best practice to protect front-end JavaScript code?

Comment: You don't. At best you can obfuscate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can just try to make your code as unreadable and complicated as possible through uglifiers/obfuscators.

Answer (score 0):

use can **JavaScript obfuscation** tools, like [javascriptobfuscator](http://javascriptobfuscator.com/). but JavaScript codes can be stolen because JavaScript doesn't compile, it interpreted in the browser.